# JAX-RS return a collection of your custom object?

Tags: jpa, jax-rs

I have a webservice that uses JAX-RS, JPA and JAXB. I've writen a method that should return a collection of objects from my database. This doesn't happen though. It only return a single item.

My method:

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Path("findMeasurementsByRunID/{runID}")
    public List<Measurement> getMeasurementByRunId(@PathParam("runID") int runID) {
        List<Measurement> results = null;
        Query query = emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery(
                "findMeasurementsByRunID");
        query.setParameter("runid", runID);
        results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
```

My Entity-class:

```
    @Entity
    @NamedQueries({
            @NamedQuery(name = "findMeasurementsByRunID", query = "SELECT m "
                    + "FROM Measurement m "
                    + "WHERE m.runID = :runid"),
            @NamedQuery(name = "findMeasurementsByRunIDPosition", query = "SELECT m "
                    + "FROM Measurement m "
                    + "WHERE m.runID = :runid AND "
                    + "m.position = :position") })
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlType(propOrder = { "runID", "rack", "position", "completionStatus",
            "countingTime", "cr51Counts", "cr51CPM", "cr51Error",
            "measurementDateTime", "protocolID", "protocolName" })
    public class Measurement implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @AttributeOverrides({
                @AttributeOverride(name = "runID", column = @Column(name = "RunID")),
                @AttributeOverride(name = "position", column = @Column(name = "Position")) })
        @Column(name = "RunID")
        private int runID;

        @Column(name = "Rack")
        private int rack;

        @Column(name = "Position")
        private int position;

        @Column(name = "Completionstatus")
        private int completionStatus;

        @Column(name = "CountingTime")
        private double countingTime;

        @Column(name = "Cr51Counts")
        private double cr51Counts;

        @Column(name = "Cr51CPM")
        private double cr51CPM;

        @Column(name = "Cr51Error")
        private double cr51Error;

        @Column(name = "MeasurementDateTime")
        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        private Date measurementDateTime;

        @Column(name = "ProtocolID")
        private int protocolID;

        @Column(name = "ProtocolName")
        private String protocolName;

        public Measurement() {
        }

            // Getters and Setters...
}
```

If I call the service it only returns the first item from the query as xml not the whole collection.

Output:

```
<measurements>
  <measurement>
    <runID>418</runID>
    <rack>57</rack>
    <position>1</position>
    <completionStatus>0</completionStatus>
    <countingTime>3599.97</countingTime>
    <cr51Counts>2225.53</cr51Counts>
    <cr51CPM>5.11</cr51CPM>
    <cr51Error>44.26</cr51Error>
    <measurementDateTime>2012-12-14T14:08:37.0</measurementDateTime>
    <protocolID>3</protocolID>
    <protocolName>Cr-51 GFR (almindelig blodproever)</protocolName>
  </measurement>
</measurements>
```

How can I make the service return the whole collection of measurements and not just one item?

My data:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you execute some query "findMeasurementsByRunID" which restricts it to a particular "runId" and you don't understand why you only get 1 Measurement object? Update your query to remove/change the filter so that it allows multiples

Comment: There are multiple entries per runID. Key is composite and consists of runid and position..

Comment: runID is the "Id" of the class, yes, so its the PK, so how are there multiple rows per runID ? or do you have some extra "Id" field that is secret? Maybe "position" is also supposed to be part of the PK ? in which case mark it as that, and define an ObjectIdClass. Then return what is the SQL being invoked by your JPA provider

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it works. Turns out I hadn't created the entity-class from the newest version of my databaseschema.